# How to modify the list/vector argument in place in the R function lapply?

Tags: r, lapply

Perhaps an odd question but I have a real use case for it: is it possible to modify in place, i.e. when the function runs and not on a copy, the list/vector argument in the `lapply` function in R? And if yes, how to do it?
I need it because of some (desired) side effects.
To be more specific, after each element of the list/vector argument is 'read' (or 'used') by `lapply`, I need to delete it.

Best regards,

Olivier

Some code to illustrate what I am looking for.

`Blocked` is an atomic vector and `B` a list.

```
Unblock <- function(M)
{
    Blocked[M] <<- FALSE
    Length_B_M <- length(B[[M]])
    if(Length_B_M > 0)
    {
        # Vectorised version
        UnblockAndUpdateAdjacencyList <- function(Node.Value)
        {
            Node.Name <- as.character(Node.Value)
            Node.Value <<- NULL # This is not correct because it won't delete the argument in place
            if(Blocked[Node.Name])  Unblock(Node.Name)
        }
        lapply(X = B[[M]], FUN = UnblockAndUpdateAdjacencyList)         
        # Unvectorised version
        # 'i' is a vector/list index - integer
        # Important: it is necessary to browse items backwards as items from the atomic vector 'B[[M]]' are deleted and thus its length decreases at each iteration
        for(i in Length_B_M:1)
        {
            P <- as.character(B[[M]][i])
            B[[M]] <<- B[[M]][-i]
            if(Blocked[P])  Unblock(P)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible for a few reasons. lapply iteration is isolated.  Part of the optimization of lapply is that it knows how big of a list it needs to allocate for return. You probably need a good old fashioned loop

Comment: Thank you, @SmokeyShakers, for your reply. Yes, I think so too. The good old fashioned loop is indeed in my code under the `Unvectorised version` comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found a somewhat elegant solution, i.e. without any explicit loop and any copy of the vector/list in the argument of `lapply`.

```
Unblock <- function(M)
    {
        Blocked[M] <<- FALSE
        Length_B_M <- length(B[[M]])
        if(Length_B_M > 0)
        {
            # Vectorised version
            # One solution is to copy the vector/list in the argument of 'lapply' - Actually not even needed
            UnblockAndUpdateAdjacencyList <- function(Node.Value)
            {
                Node.Name <- as.character(Node.Value)
                B[[M]] <<- B[[M]][-1]
                if(Blocked[Node.Name])  Unblock(Node.Name)
            }
            #B_M_copy <- B[[M]]
            #lapply(X = B_M_copy, FUN = UnblockAndUpdateAdjacencyList)
            lapply(X = B[[M]], FUN = UnblockAndUpdateAdjacencyList)
        }
    }
```